# How to navigate back to previous fragment using Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am using navigation component in my app.I have three fragment in my app `Home`, `Cart` and `Cake`. I want to navigate to the desired fragment on pressing back arrow in action bar. When I am clicking on back arrow it is not switching to desired fragment rather than going back to `Home` fragment.

Below is my code:

**CartFragment.java**

```
OnBackPressedCallback back = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.fragment);
            navController.navigate(R.id.cakeFragment);
        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getActivity(),back);
```

Answer (score -1):

To intercept the back button click you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            handleBackPress()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: How can i implement this in fragment.

Comment: Just copy and paste

Comment: i  am usinng this ` @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(),R.id.fragment);
            navController.navigate(R.id.cakeFragment);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }` but its not navigating to the desired fragment.